# How to extract more than 10,000 elastic search results from a rest api endpoint

Tags: json, rest, elasticsearch

I have a POST API REST endpoint:

`https://api.qa.my-server.com/abc/def/order/_startScroll?offset=0&limit=10000&fields=`

that hits an elasticsearch server. In the JSON body we pass the following:

```
{
    "@type": "SearchDetails",
    "@baseType": "SearchDetails",
    "@schemaLocation": "",
    "name": "myStuff",
    "filter": [
        {
            "@type": "FilterGroup",
            "@baseType": "FilterGroup",
            "@schemaLocation": "",
            "filter": [
                {
                    "@type": "AttributeFilter",
                    "@baseType": "AttributeFilter",
                    "@schemaLocation": "",
                    "field": "source.sourceSystemId",
                    "value": [
                        "test"
                    ],
                    "operator": "eq",
                    "caseInsensitive": "true"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "AttributeFilter",
                    "@baseType": "AttributeFilter",
                    "@schemaLocation": "",
                    "field": "lastUpdated",
                    "value": [
                        "2023-05-06T16:35:00"
                    ],
                    "operator": "gte",
                    "caseInsensitive": "true"
                }
            ],
            "groupOperator": "AND",
            "groupModifier": "null"
        }
    ],
    "sort": [
        {
            "field": "source.orderDate",
            "direction": "DESC"
        }
    ]
}
```

This search query only returns 10,000 elasticsearch requests which is the max limit, I wanted to use scroll or something else to retrieve all the results (there are about 1,000,000 results).

The api endpoint has parameters `limit` that is basically the size of the result set.

Answer (score 0):

You should set index settings:

```
"max_result_window": 1000000
```

Its not recommended for performance reasons. This define max documents to retrive based on from and size parameter ( from + size cannot be higher than used settings)

Comment: I cannot change the settings for that elasticsearch index I don't know the index name, I just use post request to query from it, it is not within my privileges

Comment: That's not possible you must use some strategy pagination